# Is there some way I can limit OneDrive's upload speed lower than 50 KB/s?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, onedrive

I'm on a very low-speed connection. OneDrive only allows you to change this as low as 50 KB/s. Is there some way, maybe through the registry, that I can bypass this, to set it to 20 KB/s? I'm on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: Here is an article with the registry setting for lower rates: .....  https://admx.help/?Category=OneDrive&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.OneDriveNGSC::UploadBandwidthLimit

Comment: @John Unfortunately, I'm not seeing `UploadBandwidthLimit` on Windows 11.

Comment: Part way down the right side:     Select the maximum amount of bandwidth to take up when uploading files.

Valid values are from 1 to 100000.

Comment: I took a careful look, and I think the article is for One Drive for Business, so it may not apply. I do not (yet) see another method.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft article
[Change the OneDrive sync app upload or download rate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-onedrive-sync-app-upload-or-download-rate-71cc69da-2371-4981-8cc8-b4558bdda56e)
says this :

> 1. Open OneDrive settings (select the OneDrive cloud icon in your notification area, and then select the OneDrive Help and Settings icon
>    then Settings.)
> 2. Go to the Sync and back up tab, and expand Advanced settings.
> 3. Adjust the upload and download rates as required.

Although the minimum rate that can be set is 1 KB/s and the
maximum rate is 100000 KB/s, any input lower than 50 KB/s will
set the limit to 50 KB/s, even if the UI shows the inputted rate.

The registry setting can be found at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive`,
item [UploadBandwidthLimit](https://admx.help/?Category=OneDrive&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.OneDriveNGSC::UploadBandwidt),
but it will also be ignored if set below 50 KB/s.

This means that you need a third-party application.

The article
[How to Limit Any Application’s Bandwidth on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/347711/how-to-limit-any-applications-bandwidth-on-windows/)
describes how to use
[TMeter Freeware Edition](http://www.tmeter.ru/en/),
which might not be a perfect solution to your problem.

It also describes the more sophisticated
[NetLimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/),
which is not free and is priced at $19/year with
a 28-day trial period.

Another alternative is
[NetBalancer](https://netbalancer.com/),
priced at  $49.95.

Comment: This forces a minimum of 50 KB/s for the upload limit. I'm trying to go lower.

Comment: Right - I dug deeper into the question and added to my answer all the options I could think of.